# update .bashrc file to locate opencv libraries

Tags: bash, opencv, path

I am not a sudo user in a server and want to use my version of opencv.
There is .bashrc file for each user. I too have it. Please tell how to set path of local installation of opencv into .bashrc.
Each time I set path in .bashrc and do source ~/.bashrc. And check the version, its still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're adding the correct path and that you're appending it at the end of `$PATH` (i.e. `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/opencv`).

Then do a `source ~/.bashrc` and verify what path is being used using `which opencv`.